# MySQL ORDER BY two fields condition

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a problem with creating select query ordered by following logic:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE 1 ORDER BY Stock > 0, Price DESC
```

Table sample:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| Product | Price | Stock |
+---------+-------+-------+
| Car     |  3500 |    30 |
| Boat    |  7500 |     6 |
| Bike    |   150 |   220 |
| Plane   | 55000 |     0 |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

The desired result is, that the table will be ordered by price if the stock value is greater than 0.

So the result should be:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| Product | Price | Stock |
+---------+-------+-------+
| Boat    |  7500 |     6 |
| Car     |  3500 |    30 |
| Bike    |   150 |   220 |
| Plane   | 55000 |     0 |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of a comparison in MySQL is `0` or `1`. So `Stock > 0` is  `1` if `true`. And `1` and greather than `0`. So either use

```
ORDER BY Stock = 0 ASC, Price DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY Stock > 0 DESC, Price DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY case when Stock > 0
              then 1
              else 2
         end, 
         Price DESC
```