# MySQL ORDER BY combining two dates closest to today

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table

```
...         | reservation_from         | reservation_to         | ...
1           | 2016-05-13 10:00:00      | 2016-05-21 10:00:00    | ...
2           | 2016-05-13 20:00:00      | 2016-06-29 14:00:00    | ...
3           | 2016-05-01 10:00:00      | 2016-05-13 16:00:00    | ...
```

now i have to order and get reservations for closest day to today.

For example now is 2016-05-13, so no matter if reservation is going to start or going to end, i have to get results closest to current time. I want to order that like that

```
...         | reservation_from         | reservation_to         | ...
1           | 2016-05-13 10:00:00      | 2016-05-21 10:00:00    | ...
2           | 2016-05-01 10:00:00      | 2016-05-13 16:00:00    | ...
3           | 2016-05-13 20:00:00      | 2016-06-29 14:00:00    | ...
```

As you see, the second result `reservation_from` is 05-01 but its `reservation_to` is less than 3rd `reservation_from`

I dont know if I'm clear with the question, if no, please comment it what should i specify more.

Comment: Unless you are some time traveler today is 2016-05-13 ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ORDER BY two fields condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742718/mysql-order-by-two-fields-condition)

Comment: You need to explain what logic you use to closest to today, and also how handle tie breakers.

Comment: @mitkosoft I already viewed this answer and a lof of others, but i didnt get it :/

Comment: I edited my question with more explanations. I mean i need order by two columns reservation_from and reservation_to for example in DESC and with closest to today feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to order by the lesser time difference to now:

```
select *
from mytable
order by 
  least(abs(timestampdiff(second, now(), reservation_from)),
        abs(timestampdiff(second, now(), reservation_to)));
```

You can add futher criteria in order to deal with ties of course.

Comment: He mean when time difference is the same which one go first.

Answer (score 1):

USE **[LEAST](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/least.php)**. Will calculate the difference between each field and today, choose the smaller one.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM YourTable
 ORDER BY LEAST( ABS(TIMEDIFF(reservation_from, CURDATE()),
                 ABS(TIMEDIFF(reservation_to  , CURDATE())
               )
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Dont know. I want try it on sqlFiddle first, but is down for me now :(

Comment: I upvoted your anwser just for not being negative, but it didnt worked, sry :(

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius Dont worry you dont have to do that. But If you see the answer isnt working, just post a comment and said what is wrong (sintaxis or wrong result) and I will try to fix it

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you take a look to my question if have time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731198/how-create-groups-with-evenly-sizes   I solve it on app side but was wondering if there is a sql solution?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, first of all you missed some brackets, but anyway this query gives wrong results. I think there is some system specific/time bugs. Because your answer is very similiar to the accepted one, but he is using timestampdiff instead of timediff, and now() instead of curdate(). Btw mysql gives me "0" when i try to debug and see what CURDATE() shows to me.

Comment: I found the problem `NOW()` return `datetime`, `CURDATE()` return `date`.   http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp   So when you try to perform ( datetime - date ) doesnt work,

Comment: Also `TimeDiff` return a DATE, and give error if you calculate a negative date. That is why is better use timestampdiff because number of seconds can be negative without any problem.